# Redux fetch is returning empty

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, aws-api-gateway

My redux fetch call to my AWS API Gateway endpoint is returning empty.

Curl, Postman or just in the browser, the response is correct.

```js
export function getRequest() {
  return function (dispatch) {

    return fetch("apiGatewayURL", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  }).then(body => console.log("Calling ",JSON.stringify(body)))
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: assuming you've tested the endpoint and know that its working?

Comment: Yes the endpoint is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `json()` or `text()` function before read it.

```
export function getRequest() {
  return function (dispatch) {

    return fetch("apiGatewayURL", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(body => console.log("Calling ",JSON.stringify(body)))
  }
```

**Documentation :** https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch

**`fetch()` documentation:** https://github.com/github/fetch

Answer (score 0):

Putting `Accept` in the headers and calling `.json()` on the response first.

```
export function getRequest() {
  return function (dispatch) {

    return fetch("apiGatewayURL", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => console.log("Calling ", body))
  }
}
```